# Connect to postgresql using python script (database URI) but detects 'conn' as string

Tags: python, postgresql, connection, database-connection

I am using a simple python script to connect the postgresql and future will create the table into the postgresql just using the script.

My code is:

```
try:
    conn =  "postgresql://postgres:<password>@localhost:5432/<database_name>"
    print('connected')

except:
    print('not connected')

conn.close()
```

when I run python connect.py (my file name), it throws this error :

```
Instance of 'str' has no 'commit' member
```

pretty sure is because it detects 'conn' as a string instead of database connection. I've followed this [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/libpq-connect.html) (33.1.1.2) but now sure if Im doing it right. How to correct this code so it will connect the script to my postgresql server instead of just detects it as a string?

p/s: Im quite new to this.

Comment: ...yup. `conn` is definitely a string, and therefore has no `commit()` or `close()` method. Its value is `"postgresql://postgres:<password>@localhost:5432/<database_name>"`. Did you mean something like `conn =  psycopg2.connect("postgresql://postgres:<password>@localhost:5432/<database_name>")`?

Comment: Note that `libpq`, whose documentation you linked to, is a _C_ library, not a Python library.

Comment: The code you're showing us isn't generating that error message. There is no `commit()` in it. Please make sure to provide a [mcve] when asking questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a method on a string object.
Instead you should establish a connection to your db at first.

I don't know a driver which allows the use of a full connection string but you can use **psycopg2** which is a common python driver for PostgreSQL.

After installing **psycopg2** you can do the following to establish a connection and request your database

```
import psycopg2
try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "yourUser",
                                  password = "yourPassword",
                                  host = "serverHost",
                                  port = "serverPort",
                                  database = "databaseName")

    cursor = connection.cursor()
except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error :
    print ("Error while connecting", error)
finally:
        if(connection):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
```

You can follow this [tutorial](https://pynative.com/python-postgresql-tutorial/)